# Render UIWebView in Background

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiwebview, jqtouch

I am using an UIWebView which loads an local index.html. The index.html uses jqTouch and mimics a native iOS interface.

The problem is when the user accesses this WebView for the first time it takes about 1-2 seconds to render the page with its heavy JavaScript (jQTouch) and CSS Stuff.

This doesn't look very nice and irritates. This happens only on the first time of loading it.

Can I somehow render the WebView during the startup of the App or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Why not just write the app using native cocoa?

Comment: The main app is actually written native. It is just one section which uses an WebView for demonstration purposes...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should accept some answers if they are correct, so that people are motivated to help you in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this would work, but you can place a `UIView` with some sort of progress bar on top of the `UIWebView`, then when it's done loading remove the `UIView`.